# Error in calling javascript from angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularJS.Can i call my javascript function from angularJS ?

let say my javascript file is as follows containing a function :

test.js

```
function showAlert() {
 alert('something');
}
```

and my angular code is:

```
Script.load("test.js");
$scope.sampleFunction = function() {
                showAlert();
              };
```

currently it is not working properly. Suggestions please.

Comment: what's Script.load? if your showAlert is declared in the global namespae and your angular controller (as you have $scope in there i suppose you have a controller) is correctly included in the page then it should pick it up no problem.

Comment: all .js file path ,angular controller are well included and getting loaded to the target html page . but unable to find out whta is going wrong .

Comment: @Sai_23 : As you are not following the correct way to call a controller and function also. Can you check my answer..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an example in which i called angularJS controller and from controller calling another java script function.

Follow These Steps:

(1) Create a folder Test.

(2) Save angular.min.js from the link http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0rc1/angular.min.js.

(3) Create a file1.js Page in the same folder :

**file1.js**

```
function alertNumber(number) {
alert(number);
}
```

(4) Create file2.js Page in the same folder :

**file2.js**

```
var app = angular.module('demo',[]);

function alertOne() {
 alertNumber("one");
}
```

(5) Create index.html Page in the same folder :

**index.html**

```
<html ng-app="demo">
<head>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="file1.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="file2.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

</head>
<body>

  <div ng-controller="alertOne">

</body>
</html>
```

(6) Run the index.html Page.

**Description:** It will call the controller alertOne and alertOne will call the javascript function alertNumber with an argument.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :

```
test.js 

window.showAlert = function() {//code};


angularjs_code.js

$scope.sampleFunction = function() { window.showAlert(); }
```

But still, I strongly suggest you to transfer your old to work in angular way [ into controller, directive ... ] if you really want to learn angularJS